# Can I 'fake' an ncurses environment?

Tags: console

I'm trying to get an fm radio stick working on my streaming box. It uses the command 'radio' for tuning, but the command seems to be running in order for the radio to work (i.e. I can't just tune it then forget about it).

Unfortunately, if I try to use a wrapper that runs the command in the backgroup, it doesn't seem to work, as it is ncurses based, and doesn't seem to like being run in batch mode.

Like xvfb can be used to 'fake' an X session, can I do the same for ncurses?

Answer (score 3):

To add to Oli's answer

```
screen -d -m -S nameOfScreen /path/to/exe  #this is for scripting use
```

This is all in `man screen` and it's not too hard to figure out

You should try to find a screen tutorial to give you a once over though.
[This one](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/34) doesn't seem too bad.

Answer (score 1):

You could spawn a `screen` (`sudo apt-get install screen`) session that you can then detach from.

No idea how you'd script the detachment but it should work for keeping a ncurses application running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Direct the output to /dev/null ; this will probably keep it "happy" about not having a terminal.

`radioapp -option /etc 2>&1 > /dev/null`